# Create a public variable for a specific form

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open a new View from one of two Views (and then hide the original View).  However, when I close the new View, I want it to show the View that was hidden.

How do I store that View to a public variables so that I can reshow it, i.e. `clsVariables.ViewHidden.show();`

Hope that makes some sense (I'm kinda new to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use some screen manager class that will handle your current views or you'll need to give the form a reference to the form you want to open (or show) when it closed

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    yourForm.Show();
    base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

**EDIT**

on ViewA:

```
new ViewB(this).Show();
```

ViewB

```
public ViewA _viewA { get; set; }

public ViewB(ViewA viewA)
{
   _viewA = viewA;
   ...
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
   _viewA.Show();
   base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - but I'm not quite sure what you mean (I am new to this).  Essentially I want to store ViewA to a variable, Hide ViewA and open the new View.  When that closes, I simply want to show ViewA.

Comment: Sorry, to keep on, but what is base.OnClosed(e) - it looks useful.

Comment: base.OnClosed(e) calls Window.OnClosed. You can read about base keyword [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the help on that Tzah - I'll have a deeper read of base... (as well as everything else).